# Multi-step organic synthesis using benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, acylation

I have this project that I've been struggling with. I'm already given the reactant and product, so basically what I have to do is to figure out the steps needed to get the product.

[image: Reaction]

I figured that some of the steps would include the Friedel-Crafts acylation and nitration, but after that, I'm not too sure what other steps I'd have to take. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to  ChemSE. With some real effort on your part, we will be pleased to help. Get back to us.

Comment: How many steps are you considering?

Comment: Hint #1: Identify suitable precursors to install any of the three substitutents on a benzene ring. E.g., $\ce{-NO2}$ is introduced by ... . #2: Not all remaining $\ce{C-H}$ e.g., in nitro benzene are equal. Some substitutents direct the next entrant substitutent to _ortho_ / _para_ position, or in _meta_ position when running an electrophilic aromatic substitution. See how these patterns may align with the target of a triple substitution. #3: Some of the groups shown may the result of a substitution and subsequent group transformation  (e.g., redox). #4: Don't limit to electrophilic reaction.

Answer (score 6):

@Waylander has provided a concise route to the nitro compound in question. I am also in accord with his comments regarding the OP's effort and his assessment that benzene, as a starting material, is not a choice by a practicing chemist. Now that he has opened the door to a solution, I offer a more traditional approach.
Classical nitration of ketoacid **7** should be reasonably selective in that the introduction of the nitro group in **8** is both para and meta directed. Keto acid **7** arises from indene **6** via exhaustive oxidation. To access the indene, I would start with benzaldehyde (**2**), whose preparations from benzene (**1**) are numerous. The Perkin condensation **2** $\rightarrow$ **3** is [known](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0223523418310730). Hydrogenation of **3** forms carboxylic acid **4**, which can be cyclized to indanone **5** with polyphosphoric acid. Friedel-Crafts techniques may also be employed. Reduction of this ketone followed by dehydration leads to the critical indene **6**.

[image]

Comment: The indene cleavage is a nice option. I would be tempted to carbonylate benzene to make benzaldehyde.

Comment: @Waylander: I agree with direct carbonylation except that the ones I found on Chem. Absts. require more sophisticated techniques. I opted for something the OP would understand although it is several steps. There is also Cl2CHOCH3/TiCl4 as a CO equivalent but, again, too sophisticated. The whole post is an academic exercise, not something you or I would have executed from benzene.

Answer (score 4):

While I think the OP should make more of an effort at answering this I am going to suggest a route because I think this is an interesting challenge - if a little unreal. In the real world of preparative organic chemistry you would not be starting from benzene. There are many possible approaches to this, but here is mine

Step 1 - carbamoylation of benzene with dimethyl carbamoyl chloride/TMSOTf/Zn(OTf)2 as described [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329079333_Direct_and_Selective_C-H_Carbamoylation_of_Heteroaromatics_with_TMSOTf-Activated_Carbamoyl_Chloride)

Step 2 - directed lithiation of the dimethylbenzamide with sBuLi/TMEDA followed by quenching with the commercially available propylene oxide to install the C3 sidechain at the alcohol level.

Step 3 - oxidation with Dess-Martin periodinane to give the benzyl methyl ketone

Step 4 - nitration under standard HNO3/H2SO4 conditions [as here](https://chemlab.truman.edu/files/2015/07/Multi-2-Nitration-of-Benzoic-Acid-2017.pdf) should give the desired 1,2,5 substitution pattern as the major component.

Step 5 - amide hydrolysis under strong acid conditions with cHCl. I have chosen this over basic hydrolysis as think the formation of the anion of the starting benzyl methyl ketone activated by 2 EWGs is likely to be an unwanted complication.

Comment: The benzene rings in the carbamoylation paper appear to be activated. While toluene is the least activated, benzene is conspicuously absent as an example.

Comment: It is absent but think it will work with the addition of Zn(OTf)2